# Find out where PHP interpreter is currently stuck?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I have a PHP script that is stuck, but I do not know where in the code.

I am using Xdebug.

How can I find out on which line(s) of the code the server is currently stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Stuck? If you mean lines which take most time, then you can set xdebug to generate trace dumps and analyze them using [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) or [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/)

If you put this into your php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
```

you can generate the dumps by adding `?XDEBUG_PROFILE` to your urls. The default directory where the dumps are saved is /tmp/

Answer (score 1):

Either [trace execution](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) or use the [profiler](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).